# using Doulos TREV

Tags: regex, tcl

i downloaded Doulos trev-tcl regexp gui- but i cant get it started. is there any prefix and suffix that should be added to the regexp in order to get a match with the search string?

Comment: the prob' is that the regexp window stays orange-its incorrect regexp form.

Answer (score 0):

With Tcl's usual RE matching strategy, it looks for a match anywhere in the string (i.e., matches are not anchored unless you specifically ask for it). If your match space is “`abcde`” then using an RE of “`c`” should match the third letter only. I suggest trying something equally simple to start out with.

Comment: maybe i didnt clearfy myself. the gui doesn accept any regexp i write even a simple \d to match "3". it seems as if it is not a correct form of regexp. can you give me an example that works in your TREV?

Comment: @Chaggster: I've got no idea what it's trying to do. I can only comment on what *standard Tcl RE matching* does; I have no idea what wacky things Doulos TREV is adding in, but the usual guesses are things like anchoring (try seeing whether `.*3.*` matches something).